# IntelliJ-Spark/Scala Application - Breakpoint not working while Debug

Tags: scala, apache-spark, debugging, intellij-idea

Breakpoints are ignored in Intellij 2023.1.2 in our application. It was working with same application in older laptop that had intellij 2020.2

Comment: Please share a minimal repro project on Github. Also check the type of your breakpoints: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#breakpoint-types

Comment: Even if it were supposed to be an IntelliJ bug report, there would still be the problem that there is no minimal reproducible example. Anyway, this is not the right place for IntelliJ bug reports, so I don't know what it's doing here. Suggesting to close as no-repro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

placed .idea folder elsewhere, placed it back and re opened project. This solved the issue.